# C# events, how to raise them?

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to learn raising and handling events in C#.

Here's my simple example:

```
///////////////  creating a new BALL object ///    
ballClass ball = new ballClass();

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this should make the BALL object raise an event
    ball.onHit();
    label1.Text = "EVENT SEND";
}
   
// when event is fired, label text should change
void BallInPlayEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = "EVENT FOUND!";
}
```

and the ball class:

```
class ballClass
{
    public event EventHandler BallInPlay;
    
    public void onHit()
    {
        this.BallInPlay ///// ??? how should i raise this event?
    }
}
```

In the call I can't really understand, **how do I raise the event?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void onHit()
{
   if(BallInPlay != null)
     BallInPlay(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Comment: I would think `EventArgs.Empty` would be better than `new EventArgs()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :) yet what is this "null" thing? Should I assign some value to the event? Can't it like run empty?

Answer (score 4):

It's simple, just call the delegate directly, as in

```
BallInPlay(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The only thing you need to be careful about is a race condition, where BallInPlay is null or set to null before you call it.

The pattern to deal with that is

```
var bip = BallInPlay;
if (bip != null)
    bip(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :) yet what is this "null" thing? Should I assign some value to the event? Can't it like run empty?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to avoid testing the handler every time (as [Ed Guiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818824/c-events-how-to-raise-them/4818890#4818890) showed), it is (IMHO) easier to simply initialize the event with an empty delegate, and then call it without checking:

```
class Ball
{        
    // add an empty delegate to our handler
    public event EventHandler BallInPlay = delegate { };

    protected virtual void OnHit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // no need to check, we have at least one
        // dummy delegate in the invocation list
        BallInPlay (this, e);
    }
}
```

Actually (although Jon Skeet will probably tell you this before I finish writing this post :), the only truly thread safe event call is the one discussed by in [Jon Skeet's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx#threading).

Another important thing you should note is that classes shouldn't really fire events which reside in other classes (i.e. `OnHit` method should not be `public`). If a class has a public event (like your `BallClass`), it alone should be the one to fire this event.

Comment: Hmm. Its a public member, right? So it could be set to null outside your class, then boom if you don't check for null?

Comment: @Ed: you can only attach or detach an event handler to a public event (using `+=` and `-=`). You cannot set it to null anywhere (not even in the `Ball` class).

Comment: Yes of course you are right, even though it's possible to remove the last event handler this is harder (practically impossible?) with  anonymous delegates

Comment: @Rob: sorry I didn't see you comment right away. You are supposed to trigger the event in the class where you *declared* it. When a class fires an event, it means that it wants to notify some other parts of your code that something happened. So, if you are calling `OnHit` from the main form, then it means that the main form is the one which knows that something happened, and that it should have its own public event.