# How can I raise CanExecuteChanged() programmatically?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I need to programmatically raise `CanExecuteChanged()`. The `ICommand` class looks like this:

```
public class PlayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly TpViewModel _tpViewModel;
    private bool IsBusy;

    public PlayCommand(TpViewModel tpViewModel)
    {
        _tpViewModel = tpViewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return !IsBusy;
    }

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        await Play();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    private async Task Play()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Play")

        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

The `Play` button should be enabled as soon as the `Play()` method is completed. However, there seems to be a delay of a second or two before the button gets enabled.

I have tried `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` but it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818824/c-sharp-events-how-to-raise-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`, though this is fairly expensive. However, you can just extend your class with standard event patterns.

***Note*** : This is only an example based on your code and not intended to be the worlds best-of-class `ICommand` implementation, modify it as you need

```
private EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
   add
   {
      _canExecuteChanged += value;
      CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
   }
   remove
   {
      _canExecuteChanged -= value;
      CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
   }
}

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
   if (!IsBusy)
      OnCanExecuteChanged();
}

protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged()
   => _canExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```